# Please initialize `Bidirectional` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to recreate the SkimLit paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05251) and I am experiencing trouble when trying to Concatenate both token and character level embedding, but also with the line numbers and total line numbers. I've seen others encountering this problem, but their solutions doesn't work for me. Here's an example: https://github.com/keras-team/tf-keras/issues/556. I would be extremely grateful if anyone could help a lost soul.

This is just one hot encoding the data and prefetching it so it'll run faster.

```
# Combine chars and tokens into a dataset
train_token_char_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_sentences, train_chars))
train_char_token_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_labels_one_hot)
train_char_token_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_token_char_data, train_char_token_labels))

# Prefetch and batch train data

train_char_token_dataset = train_char_token_dataset.batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Combine chars and tokens into a dataset

val_token_char_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_sentences, val_chars))
val_char_token_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(val_labels_one_hot)
val_char_token_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((val_token_char_data, val_char_token_labels))

# Prefetch and batch train data

val_char_token_dataset = val_char_token_dataset.batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)\`

# Use tensorflow to create one-hot-encoded tensors of our "line_number" column
train_line_numbers_one_hot = tf.one_hot(train_df["line_number"].to_numpy(), depth=20)
val_line_numbers_one_hot = tf.one_hot(val_df["line_number"].to_numpy(), depth=20)
test_line_numbers_one_hot = tf.one_hot(test_df["line_number"].to_numpy(), depth=20)
train_line_numbers_one_hot[:5], train_line_numbers_one_hot.shape

# Use tensorflow to create one-hot encoded tensors of our "total_lines" feature
train_total_lines_one_hot = tf.one_hot(train_df["total_lines"].to_numpy(), depth=20)
val_total_lines_one_hot = tf.one_hot(val_df["total_lines"].to_numpy(), depth=20)
test_total_lines_one_hot = tf.one_hot(test_df["total_lines"].to_numpy(), depth=20)
train_total_lines_one_hot[:2], train_total_lines_one_hot.shape`
```

Now for the actual model:

```
# 1. Token inputs
token_inputs = layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string, name="token_inputs")
token_embeddings = tf_hub_embedding_layer(token_inputs)
token_outputs = layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(token_embeddings)
token_model = tf.keras.Model(token_inputs,token_outputs)

# 2. Char inputs
char_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, name="char_inputs")
char_vectors = char_vectorizer(char_inputs)
char_embedding = char_embed(char_vectors)
char_bi_lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(24)(char_embeddings))
char_model = tf.keras.Model(char_inputs, char_bi_lstm)

# 3. Line number feature
line_number_inputs = layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32, name="line_number_inputs")
x = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(line_numbers_inputs)
line_number_model = tf.keras.Model(line_numbers_inputs, x)

# 4. Total line number feature
total_lines_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(20,), dtype=tf.float32, name="total_lines_inputs")
y = layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(total_lines_inputs)
total_lines_model = tf.keras.Model(total_lines_inputs, y)

# 5. Combine token and char embeddings into a hybrid embedding
combined_embeddings = layers.Concatenate(name="char_token_hybrid_embedding")([token_model.output,
                                                                             char_model.output])

z = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(combined_embeddings)
z = layers.Dropout(0.5)(z)

# 6. Combine positional embedding with combined token and char embeddings
tribrid_embeddings = layers.Concatenate(name="char_token_tribrid_embedding")([line_number_model.output,
 total_lines_model.ouput,
 z])

# 7. Create output layer
output_layer = layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax", name="output_layer")(tribrid_embeddings)

# 8. Put together model with all kinds of inputs
model_5 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[line_number_model.input,
                                total_line_model.input,
                                token_model.input,
                                char_model.input],
                        outputs=output_layer)
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[123], line 11
      9 char_vectors = char_vectorizer(char_inputs)
     10 char_embedding = char_embed(char_vectors)
---> 11 char_bi_lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(24)(char_embeddings))
     12 char_model = tf.keras.Model(char_inputs, char_bi_lstm)
     14 # 3. Line number feature

File ~/Desktop/skimLit/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/rnn/bidirectional.py:118, in Bidirectional.__init__(self, layer, merge_mode, weights, backward_layer, **kwargs)
    109 def __init__(
    110     self,
    111     layer,
   (...)
    115     **kwargs,
    116 ):
    117     if not isinstance(layer, Layer):
--> 118         raise ValueError(
    119             "Please initialize `Bidirectional` layer with a "
    120             f"`tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. Received: {layer}"
    121         )
    122     if backward_layer is not None and not isinstance(backward_layer, Layer):
    123         raise ValueError(
    124             "`backward_layer` need to be a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` "
    125             f"instance. Received: {backward_layer}"
    126         )

ValueError: Please initialize `Bidirectional` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. Received: KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 24), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='lstm_19/PartitionedCall:0', description="created by layer 'lstm_19'")
```

Comment: You are not passing a layer, you are passing the output of a layer, somehow mixing the Sequential and Functional APIs, that will not work.

Comment: I solves the issue. I had some typos throughout the code, but the main issues was with this line: line_number_inputs = layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32, name="line_number_inputs") The shape should also be shape=(1,) here.